# Flutter PDF pdfGraphics.drawLine not showing on some PDF viewers and when printed

Tags: flutter, pdf, printing, line, drawing

I am making a Flutter app producing PDF by using [pdf package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) The app can generate shapes by using pw.CustomPaint and it is shown on Google Chrome's PDF viewer and Acrobat but not on PDF Expert. Also, when I try to print it, the generated lines by pw.CustomPaint not appearing probably due to too thinness.

```
generateBarredArea(int totalWidth, int width, int height, int sectionNumber) {
print("generate Barred Area");
print(
    "totalWidth: $totalWidth width: $width height: $height sectionNumber: $sectionNumber");

return pw.Container(
  width: width.toDouble(),
  height: height.toDouble(),
  child: pw.CustomPaint(
    size: PdfPoint(width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()),
    painter: (PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
      int x = width;

      for (int i = sectionNumber;
          i > 0;
          i--, x -= (totalWidth / sectionNumber).toInt()) {
        if (x > 0) {
          canvas.drawLine(x.toDouble(), 0, x.toDouble(), height.toDouble());
        }
      }

      canvas.setColor(PdfColors.black);
      canvas.setLineWidth(10.0);
      canvas.fillPath();
    },
  ),
);
```

}

I try to change canvas.setColor and canvas.setLineWidth but they didn't work. How can I change lines' thickness? Please, help me!